# appeal : legal process to a higher court or just a kind of claim

Tags: appeal

The image I attached below is the section concerning the right of appeal in Employment's Compensation Act of Nigeria. In that context, I wonder whether an 'appeal' represents a legal process to a higher court, or it means a kind of claim to the committee or company. I'm not an English-native speaker. Please, let me understand.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The decision can be appealed to the Nigeria Social Insurance Trust Fund Management Board. Any appeal of the board's decision goes to the National Industrial Court (next page).